# Characteristic polynomial and $p$-adic valuation

Tags: linear-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Suppose I had a linear operator $L$ whose characteristic polynomial was $f(x) = x^{n} + a_{1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-1}x + a_{n}$. Furthermore, I also know that the eigenvalues of $L$ have $p$-adic valuation $\geq 1$. Why does it follow that $a_{i} \in p^{i}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ for all $i$? What if all the eigenvalues have $p$-adic valuation equal to 1?

Comment: Have you tried checking this yourself for small n, say n = 1,2,3? How are eigenvalues related to the factorization of the characteristic polynomial?

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial. Now you just need to recall the relation between the roots of a (monic) polynomial and its coefficients.

Comment: Let $r_{i}$ be the roots of $f(x)$. Then by the relations between roots and coefficients, I know that $|r_{1} + \cdots + r_{n}|_{p} = |a_{1}|_{p}$. As the $p$-adic valuation is nonarchimedean, we know that $|a_{1}|_{p} \leq \max(|r_{1}|_{p}, \ldots, |r_{n}|_{p})$. How can I prove that $|a_{1}|_{p} \leq 1/p$?

Answer (score -2):

I can't comment at the moment - insufficient points. You need to go back to what the p-adic valuation means and basic facts about divisibility of integers by primes. I think it is a lot simpler than you realise.